# Error with Caffe installation (cmake command): LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

Hi when I want to run `cmake` for caffe installation it is showing me this:

```
    Target "caffe" has an INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property which differs from
          its LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES properties.

          INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES:
    proto;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.s
[...]
LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES:

    proto;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_ 
[....]
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

This is not letting me to go forward, when I ran `make all`, this error comes:

```
    [  0%] Running C++/Python protocol buffer compiler on /home/somayeh/caffe/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
    Scanning dependencies of target proto
    [  0%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/proto.dir/__/__/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc.o
    [  1%] Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libproto.a
    [  1%] Built target proto
    [  1%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/cuda_compile_generated_tile_layer.cu.o
    /usr/include/string.h: In function 'void* __mempcpy_inline(void*, const void*, size_t)':
    /usr/include/string.h:652:42: error: 'memcpy' was not declared in this scope
       return (char *) memcpy (__dest, __src, __n) + __n;
                                              ^
    CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_tile_layer.cu.o.cmake:266 (message):
      Error generating file
      /home/user/caffe/build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_tile_layer.cu.o


src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:469: recipe for target 'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/cuda_compile_generated_tile_layer.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/cuda_compile_generated_tile_layer.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:304: recipe for target 'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know how to tackle this? Thanks in advance